# Why the text in wxpython only display half if I change the text content

Tags: python, wxpython, display

I'm now using the wxpython and want to change the text content during running, here is my code:

```
import wx
import time

def button_click(event):
    label2 = wx.StaticText(panel, pos=(25, 100))
    label2.SetSize(30, -1)
    label2.SetLabelText('test_b')
    label2.SetForegroundColour((255, 0, 0))
    label2.SetFont(font)
    time.sleep(1)
    label2.SetLabelText('chang_to_test_c')
    time.sleep(2)
    label2.SetLabelText('finally_is_test_d')

app = wx.App()
window = wx.Frame(None, title='test', size=(720, 480), pos=(200, 50))
panel = wx.Panel(window, size=(720, 480))
font = wx.Font(15, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD)
button1 = wx.Button(panel, label='click', pos=(25, 50), size=(100, 30))
button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, button_click)
window.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

when I run the program and click button, it first only display 'tes' and 'chang_' like this

[image]

[image]

then display 'finally_is_test_d', why the wxpython only display half text during running, what should I do if I want to see the all text.

Comment: You may need to set the size of `wx.StaticText` appropriately. Or reduce the font size.

Comment: I have tried the <label2.SetSize(30, -1)> and set the font size to 10 while the issue still exist, and if i delete the label2.SetLabelText('finally_is_test_d')  then 'change_to_test_c' can be display completely

Comment: There is no function called `SetLabelText`. See [this](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.StaticText.html) - it should be `SetLabel`.

Comment: I change it it while doesn't work

Comment: Also, what does `SetSize(30, -1)` mean? What are you trying to do? Try changing it to 100x20 and see if there is any change.

Comment: Yes, at first I think the reason should be the size of text is too small, so I set size to a big size, but it doesn't work too

Comment: Try `import wx.lib.inspection` and put `wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()` line before `window.Show()`. It will open a window wherein you can see what values are being computed for each element.

Comment: @kiner_shah In this case, I think you're correct but `SetLabelText` is valid and subtlely different to `SetLabel` https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Control.html#wx.Control.SetLabel

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, oh I see, it's a method from a parent class wx.Control. Thanks for pointing that out :-)

Comment: `Sizers` are tricky beasts but this is where their magic works best, automatically resizing widgets as and when required. Take a look at: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/sizers_overview.html

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong to sleep :-)

You must remember that everything in the wxPython program is hapenning in the event loop - app.MainLoop().

Event loop calls your button_click function. It does the following:

- change the text
- sleep
- change the text
- sleep
- change the text again

After button_click has run, the event loop has another chance to process events and therefore redraw or re-do layout.

There are 2 things I recommend:

- Look at wx.Timer - that will help you run things later or repeatedly
- Look at sizers. It is usually prefered to use sizers to layout your widgets instead of absolute sizing.

Answer (score 1):

As I said, you need to set the text box size appropriately in order to avoid text clipping. Also, since that label is created for a button click event, it should be destroyed at the end of the function.

I moved the setting the initial label and size part in the constructor itself.

Agree with @PetrBlahos, avoid sleeps in event listener functions and sizers are cool :-)

```
import wx
#import wx.lib.inspection
import time

def button_click(event):
    label2 = wx.StaticText(panel, label = "test_b", size = (720, 30), pos = (25, 100))
    #print(font)
    label2.SetForegroundColour((255, 0, 0))
    label2.SetFont(font)
    
    time.sleep(2)
    label2.SetLabel('chang_to_test_c')
    time.sleep(2)
    label2.SetLabel('finally_is_test_d')
    time.sleep(2)
    label2.Destroy()

app = wx.App()
window = wx.Frame(None, title='test', size=(720, 480), pos=(200, 50))
panel = wx.Panel(window, size=(720, 480))
font = wx.Font(15, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD)
button1 = wx.Button(panel, label='click', pos=(25, 50), size=(100, 30))
button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, button_click)
#wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
window.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Also, as per comment from @RolfofSaxony, you can also use `SetLabelText` method which is derived from `wx.Control`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, the reason is that each text size is different while wxpython will use the former size to display the later text,
I have changed the code as below:

```
def button_click(event):
    label2 = wx.StaticText(panel, pos=(25, 100))
    label2.SetLabel('test_b           ')
    label2.SetForegroundColour((255, 0, 0))
    label2.SetFont(font)
    time.sleep(2)
    label2.SetLabel('chang_to_test_c  ')
    time.sleep(2)
    label2.SetLabel('finally_is_test_d')
    label2.Destroy()
```

Then it works